# How to fetch record of many IDs on single query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This is my table. When the Done is clicked it picks the checked checkbox IDs and shows in a textbox. On the PDF button click it posts the textbox input to another page:

[image]

So i want to Fetch the details of all the id's but my code only show the first id's result

```
if (isset($_POST['allids'])) {
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order
 WHERE order_id = '".$_POST['allids']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo $row['order_no']."</br>";
  echo $row['ordercustomer_name']."</br>";
 }

}
```

This is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="fetch3.php" target="_blank">
 <div class="container" id="order_data">

</div>

<div>
  <h4><strong>GENERATE REPORT</strong></h4>      
  <input type="text" name="allids" id="allids">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn_done" name="btn_done" id="btn_done"><i class='fa'></i> DONE</button>     
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn_pdf" name="btn_pdf" id="btn_pdf"><i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o'></i> PDF</button>     
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Take a look at the `IN ()` syntax in the mysql manual, to replace your `=`

Comment: You should use a prepared statement with bound variables. And you cannot use `=` for that, you would need `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: where is the form / HTML for this and the db schema with values? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You keep commenting under the second answer, but said nothing in the first one. I asked for more code but you choose to remain silent. You came here asking for help, so help us help you.

Comment: sorry sir i update quection now

Answer (score 0):

You would use an `IN` statement in your SQL query, having a comma separated group of the ID's:

```
WHERE order_id IN (695,392)
```

WARNING: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Specifically for `IN` use [these instructions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)

Comment: I suspect `$_POST['allids'] == "695,392"`. doing prepared statement will provide `WHERE order_id IN ('695,392')` which is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean @Cid? I sucessfully produce comma separated variables for use in `IN` statements all of the time.

Answer (score -2):

you can acheive it with :

```
if (isset($_POST['allids'])) {
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order
 WHERE order_id in('".$_POST['allids']."')";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo $row['order_no']."</br>";
  echo $row['ordercustomer_name']."</br>";
 }

}
```

Comment: convert input of that variable $_POST['allids'] like '695,392'

Comment: how could i convert please explain

Comment: @AnkitKumar you're creating a single string `'695,392'` which to MySQL looks like a single value. You have to create an array from the ID's so it looks like `'695','392'`

Comment: give me some example

Answer (score -2):

now its work fine thank you all of U

```
$id = $_POST['allids'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order
WHERE order_id IN($id)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['order_id']."</br>";
 echo $row['order_no']."</br>";
 echo $row['ordercustomer_name']."</br>";
}
```

Comment: There is no way this works as you are passing a single string of numbers (`$id`) to the query.

Comment: Well, this can work since this isn't parameterized. This is pretty bad and unsafe, but this can work. `$id = "1,2,3";` -> `"IN($id)"` gives `"IN(1,2,3)"`. Good luck trusting your user's inputs. Why would one write bullet proof code when you can spend nights fixing easily-avoided security breaches in production.